# Can you really drink from Root Beer Barrels?

Tags: realism, pee-wees-big-holiday

[image]

In *Pee-wee's Big Holiday*, we often see someone grab a candy "Root Beer Barrel" and use a tiny straw to drink the Root Beer inside the candy. I've never tried this candy before and when I was researching online I couldn't determine **whether you can actually drink from Root Beer Barrels**.

Comment: Its just a gag. The movie portrays all kinds of things that don't make sense in the real world. Its PeeWee Herman.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Root Beer Barrel candy, as far as I've had **in real life**, are hard candy. They do not have a liquid center. So no.

Obviously, there may be variations on the candy throughout the country or even world, or specialty/designer/indie/souvenir candy manufacturers who make it as the movie describe. You never know.

Comment: so, in-universe, they were just _pretending_ to drink from it?

Comment: @RedCaio you are asking about realism, or real world. In-universe the candies could be different. And It's Pee-Wee so yea, maybe he's just pretending. If you're asking for in-universe you need to update your question to reflect that.

Comment: well, I don't want to invalidate your existing answer, but now that it seems there's no liquid inside in real life, I'm wondering whether they're is lquid inside in-universe where they drinking it or just pretending. If it wouldn't bother you, I can add that to my question. Or if it would, I can ask a new question. :)

Comment: Ping a mod and see what they recommend

Comment: "Ping a mod" ... what did you call me?

Comment: You could flag your question with a "moderator attention" or do @ username. @RedCaio